# order making for a matrix in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, matrix, signal-processing

I am doing a simulation on a matrix (suppose a 5x5 matrix). One of the elements of this matrix is known (the back square in below; this location will not be always in center) and I want to start from that location and spirally visit the other elements (I have shown the orders in number). How I can define this order in a large matrix (e.g. 1000x1000)? Because I cannot do it manually and I am looking for a more heuristic way.

I used *bwdist* in matlab and then sort the obtained matrix, but the results were not as what I want.

Any better solution?

[image]

Comment: What is the ordering when element picked is not in the center?

Comment: Check out this algorithm - it will give you a slightly different spiral though: http://cnr.lwlss.net/RasterArchimedes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When element is in the center, just use the [`spiral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/images-and-matrices.html) command:

```
>> spiral(5)

ans =

    21    22    23    24    25
    20     7     8     9    10
    19     6     1     2    11
    18     5     4     3    12
    17    16    15    14    13
```

For arbitrary position of the starting point we'll need to do something by hands

Let's exploit this fancy `spiral` function. To obtain the answer matrix `A`, make the bigger matrix `M` where the starting point is in the center. Note that relative order of the elements in `A` and in `M` is the same. All we need is to get `A` as a submatrix from `M` and fill it with continuous array of elements in the same order:

```
function A = spiral_generic(n, P)
% Makes NxN matrix filled up spirally starting with point P
  r = max([P - 1, n - P]);              % Radius of the bigger matrix
  M = spiral(2 * r + 1);                % Bigger matrix itself
  C = r + 1 - (P - 1);                  % Top-left corner of A in M
  A = M(C(1):C(1)+n-1, C(2):C(2)+n-1);  % Get the submatrix
  [~, order] = sort(A(:));              % Get elements' order
  A(order) = 1:n^2;                     % Fill with continous values
end
```

And here's how it works:

```
>> spiral_generic(5, [3 2])

ans =

    17    18    19    20    21
     7     8     9    10    22
     6     1     2    11    23
     5     4     3    12    24
    16    15    14    13    25

>> spiral_generic(6, [2 5])

ans =

    36    25    16     7     8     9
    35    24    15     6     1     2
    34    23    14     5     4     3
    33    22    13    12    11    10
    32    21    20    19    18    17
    31    30    29    28    27    26
```

This is not the fastest solution since it requires sorting and thus takes `O(N^2 logN)` time comparing to direct `O(N^2)` implementation. But it is very short and works fast enough for matrices around 1000x1000.

Comment: I edited the question and as you see, I need something like spiral command in matlab by which I define the from which location it should start.